# docker don't create container psql in ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'm type command

> sudo docker run --name=todo-db -e POSTGRESS_PASSWORD='1234' -p 5436:5432 -d --rm postgres

After which I get "030cdf850...."

Input

> sudo docker ps -a

and I get an empty table

Comment: You ran `--rm`, which automatically removes the container when it exits. Your container likely exited.

Comment: Okay, now it is exilted. How can I run it?

Comment: `postgres` usually only has one `s` at the end.  Does it say something more interesting if you run it without `-d`?

Comment: I made a typo in the code. But with 1 s it still doesn't work

Comment: With 1 S it works for me. If you still have issues, remove `--rm` and add the logs from the container to your post.

Answer (score 1):

try this command to run your psql in ubuntu. Good luck...

```
docker run --rm -it -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=InitialDB postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're trying to use `--rm` for database instance, but here is why you can't create:

```
-e POSTGRESS_PASSWORD='1234'
```

is not correct. You have two `S` in your environment variable while it should has only one `S`. If you remove `--rm` and run it again, then run `docker logs todo-db`, you'll see this:

```
Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
       You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
       superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".

       You may also use "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" to allow all
       connections without a password. This is *not* recommended.

       See PostgreSQL documentation about "trust":
       https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
```

. So, use this:

```
docker run --name=todo-db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD='1234' -p 5436:5432 -d --rm postgres
```

Also keep in mind that to debug the reason why container is not created, do not use `--rm` to see the exited one in `docker ps -a` output to check the logs.